# Need help in learning Qt for Nokia phones

Tags: qt, nokia

I'm trying to learn how to program qt.  I know c++ very well, and have been able to do the standard hellow world program.  I cannot find any books or documention on qt.  I did find a tutriol,at
http://www.digitalfanatics.org/projects/qt_tutorial/chapter01.html  but the project would not compile, said it could not find include file #include .

Does anubofy know of a book or anything that will tell you how to program the qt frame work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comprehensive list of books over at [Qt Developer Network](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/books).

And the documentation for Qt is quite good, with [several tutorials](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials.html) as a great place to start.

The link you are directing to above is referring to an old version of Qt, I would guess. The page at least seems to be dated back to 2004. Qt has gone a long way since then, especially when it comes to tools.

Using Qt Creator is probably the best way to start working with Qt applications, as it handles most of the setup needed to get started with a Qt project without having to resort too often to the command line (unless that is how you prefer to do it, of course.)

For Nokia phones you should check out the QML framework for any GUI you're making. Qt Creator has a simple designer for QML and you'll probably find some good help in the [QML Getting Started tutorial](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/gettingstartedqml.html).

It is easily connected to anything you make in C++, but gives you more ease and freedom in making user interfaces. But if you prefer to do everything in C++, all the things you can do in QML can be done using only C++ end as well.

Answer (score 0):

The book [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) is the definitive guide to programming Qt, I think. But you can also learn much from the Qt documentation itself, if you know where to start. The Qt documentation is really good and extensive, a perfect reference. And as Qt is also very intuitive, the doc can also help you find new functionality (If you have an idea, how some feature could be realized in Qt, it is often realized just that way).